# Setting folder permissions using NSIS

Tags: permissions, directory, nsis, runas

I am attempting to set an open folder permission (i.e. Everyone has Full Access) using NSIS with RunAsW plugin that calls cscript.exe in an elevated user permissions.

As follows:

```
Function ReplaceEXE

ClearErrors

SetOutPath '$TEMP'
File 'RunAs.dll'

File 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe'

StrCpy $1 "adminaccount"
StrCpy $2 "!adminpassword"
StrCpy $3 '"$TEMP\C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe" //Nologo XCACLS.vbs    "C:\OpenAccessFolder" /F /T /E /G Everyone:M'
StrCpy $4 0

System::Call 'RunAs::RunAsW(w r1,w r2,w r3,*w .r4) i .r0 ? u'

DetailPrint "Permissions have been edited correctly"
DetailPrint "End installation"

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what happens when you run this script, someone might be able to help, i.e. does it crash, does it just not set the permission?

Comment: Why are you installing cscript.exe? "$TEMP\C:\..." is not a valid path! I'm not sure if XCACLS.vbs is a part of windows...

Comment: You should use $PLUGINSDIR and not $TEMP for your temp files (That folder is deleted on installer exit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [AccessControl plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) to set permissions in NSIS.

If you need [administrator privileges](http://pastebin.com/EvMkyLLt) you should ask for that at the start of the installer...